# What should I use as a lock object of a synchronized statement in Java

Tags: java, object, synchronization

Could anyone explain what is the difference between these examples?

**Example # 1.**

```
public class Main {

    private Object lock = new Object();
    private MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

    public void testMethod() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        synchronized (myClass) {
            // TODO: modify myClass variable
        }
    }

}
```

**Example # 2.**

```
package com.test;

public class Main {

    private MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    private Object lock = new Object();

    public void testMethod() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        synchronized (lock) {
            // TODO: modify myClass variable
        }
    }

}
```

What should I use as a monitor lock if I need to take care about synchronization when modifying the variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `Main` is not intended to be a "leaky abstraction", here is minimal difference between the first and second examples.

It may be better to use an `Object` rather than some other class because an `Object` instance has no fields and is therefore smaller.  And the `Object`-as-lock idiom makes it clear that the `lock` variable is intended to only ever used as a lock.

Having said that, there is a definite advantage in locking on an object that nothing else will ever see.  The problem with a `Main` method synchronizing on a `Main` (e.g. `this`) is that other unrelated code could also be synchronizing on it for an unrelated purpose.  By synchronizing on dedicated (private) lock object you avoid that possibility.

---

In response to the comment:

> There is a MAJOR difference in the two cases. In the first you're locking the object that you want to manipulate. In the second you're locking some other object that has no obvious relationship to the object being manipulated. And the second case takes more space, since you must allocate the (otherwise unused) Object, rather than using the already-existing instance you're protecting.

I think you are making an INCORRECT assumption - that `MyClass` is the data structure that needs protecting.  In fact, the Question doesn't say that.  Indeed the way that the example is written implies that the lock is intended to protect the entire `Main` class ... not just a part of its state.  And in that context, there IS an obvious connection ...

The only case where it would be better to lock the `MyClass` would be if the `Main` was a leaky abstraction that allowed other code to get hold of its `myClass` reference.  That would be bad design, especially in a multi-threaded app.

Based on the revision history, I'm pretty sure that is not the OP's intention.

Comment: thank you. Indeed, the second example began making more sense after your explanation.

Comment: There is a MAJOR difference in the two cases.  In the first you're locking the object that you want to manipulate.  In the second you're locking some other object that has no obvious relationship to the object being manipulated.  And the second case takes more space, since you must allocate the (otherwise unused) Object, rather than using the already-existing instance you're protecting.

Answer (score 3):

The statement synchronization is useful when changing variables of an object.

You are changing variables of `myClass` so you want to lock on `myClass` object. If you were to change something in `lock` then you want to lock on `lock` object.

In example #2 you are modifying `myClass` but locking on `lock` object which is nonsense.

Comment: There is no problem with locking 'lock' and modifying 'myClass'. There may be a problem when if in some other part in the code 'myClass' is updated without acquiring 'lock' or using some other mechanism that prevents simultaneous change. Example #2 does make sense in many cases.

Comment: @Amit Where did I say that there is a problem with locking `lock` and modifying `myClass` ? I didn't. Can you show me a single example when #2 is reasonable?

Comment: I've checked the edits in the original questions... example #2 was changed from the time you posted your answer to the time I made that comment... I can show you many cases in which the current example #2 is reasonable... but I assume you've meant the old one which was less reasonable @martini

Comment: I mean the current example. Where both `lock` and `myClass` are global.

Answer (score 2):

In first case you lock on object that it known only within this method, so it is unlikely that anybody else will use the same object to lock on, so such lock is almost useless.  Second variant makes much more sense for me.

At the same time, myClass variable is also known only within this method, so it is unlikely that other thread will access it, so probably lock is not necessary here at all.  Need more complete example to say more.

Comment: of course, I should have put `myClass` out of the method. I have just edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

The difference are the class of the lock and its scope
- Both topics are pretty much orthogonal with synchronization

- objects with different classes may have different sizes
- objects in different scopes may be available in different contexts

Basically both will behave the same in relation to synchronization

Comment: You didn't seem to actually say anything.

Comment: That's because there is no good answer... it depends on the specific use case: on the data he needs with the lock and the scope in which he need that data... the synchronized part isn't really relevant

Answer (score 1):

In general, you want to lock on the "root" object of the data you're manipulating.  If you're, eg, going to subtract a value from a field in object A and add that value to object B, you need to lock some object that is somehow common (at least by convention) between A and B, possibly the "owner" object of the two.  This is because you're doing the lock to maintain a "contract" of consistency between separate pieces of data -- the object locked must be common to and conceptually encompassing of the entire set of data that must be kept consistent.

The simple case, of course, is when you're modifying field A and field B in the same object, in which case locking that object is the obvious choice.

A little less obvious is when you're dealing with static data belonging to a single class.  In that case you generally want to lock the class.

A separate "monitor" object -- created only to serve as a lockable entity -- is rarely needed in Java, but might apply to, say, elements of two parallel arrays, where you want to maintain consistency between element N of the two arrays.  In that case, something like a 3rd array of monitor objects might be appropriate.

(Note that this is all just a "quick hack" at laying out some rules.  There are many subtleties that one can run into, especially when attempting to allow the maximum of concurrent access to heavily-accessed data.  But such cases are rare outside of high-performance computing.)

Whatever you choose, it's critical that the choice be *consistent* across all references to the protected data.  You don't want to lock object A in one case and object B in another, when referencing/modifying the same data.  (And PLEASE don't fall into the trap of thinking you can lock an arbitrary instance of Class A and that will somehow serve to lock another instance of Class A.  That's a classical beginner's mistake.)

In your above example you'd generally want to lock the created object, assuming the consistency you're assuring is all internal to that object.  But note that in this particular example, unless the constructor for MyClass somehow lets the object address "escape", there is no need to lock at all, since there is no way that another thread can get the address of the new object.

Comment: > And PLEASE don't fall into the trap of thinking you can lock an arbitrary instance of Class A and that will somehow serve to lock another instance of Class A. That's a classical beginner's mistake.

I had made the mistake a few times before I understood it.

Answer (score 0):

Both examples are not good syncronisation practise.
The `lock  Object` should be placed in `MyClass` as private field.

Comment: I did not attach improtance to the fact that `lock` should be a private field. I have just edited the question.