# Synchronizing an ArrayList

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

Can you synchronize an ArrayList like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

synchronized (myList) {
    // add, delete, and modify list here is okay
}
```

I cannot use synchronized ArrayList returned by `Collections` utility class so is above code okay?

Comment: We need to do synchronization ourselves

Comment: Yes. In fact any object could be used as a lock. It would be syntactically valid. Whether it is good from a design perspective depends on what you want to do inside the block (the answer to which would perhaps be "no")

Comment: So if I want to modify the list, it's not a good idea to use the list as a lock?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735500/what-should-i-use-as-a-lock-object-of-a-synchronized-statement-in-java

Comment: I don't see any issue using the `synchronized` in this way. If you need an explicit lock instead of `myList`, you can create an Object called lock or use `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock` directly. Actually, I'm not sure whether the lock is still valid if you reassign `myList` to null inside the `synchronized` block, though I don't think you will do it like this.

Comment: There will be no issue.

Comment: @SupunWijerathne if you read my original question. I said I can't use synchronized collections java provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `synchronize`on any Java `Òbject` and `ArrayList` too is an `Òbject`, so its a valid syntax but since you have written in commented code that,

> // add, delete, and modify list here is okay

I guess , functionally this not what you want to achieve. I think, you want to add, delete and modify to `ArrayList`in a synchronized way when multiple threads try to access that piece of code.

If you do `synchronized (myList)`, you are simply using list as a lock and nothing else i.e. this doesn't make operations on `myList` thread safe.

Instead of that, you should do `synchronized (this)` where `this` is an instance of class containing sample code listed by you then within that block you perform operations on `myList` like adding element, deleting element etc.

`synchronized (myList)` is not functionally correct if you are looking for a replacement of `Collections.synchronizedList` because each thread will hold a lock on new object since you are doing `new ArrayList<Integer>()` for every new thread. You need to synchronize on **same object** for each thread.

Also, you don't need a synchronized access to list at all if `myList`is not a field shared by multiple threads since you are creating a new ÀrrayList`every time so each caller thread works on a new list.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement with effort.

You can use a [synchronizedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)),

Ex:

```
List myList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```